# Get FontFamily of TextBox as string XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

How do I get the `FontFamily` of a `TextBox` from code-behind as `string`? `<Element Name>.FontFamily.ToString();` returns does not return the font family; it returns 'Windows.UI.XAML.Media.FontFamily'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.source(v=vs.110).aspx

> FontFamily.Source: Gets the font family name that is used to construct
>   the FontFamily object.
>   FontFamily.ToString(): Returns the value of the Source property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it into a variable first:

```
FontFamily font = element.FontFamily;
string fontString = font.ToString();
```

To avoid storing it into a `FontFamily`-variable you could use:

```
string fontString = element.FontFamily.Source.ToString();
```